Deserialize JSON objects do different class names
I am using System.Text.Json to deserialize objects from an external API call in C#.  I have created the classes for the data and is very straight-forward.
public class DocumentListRoot
{
    public List<LevelDocumentList> LevelDocumentList { get; set; }
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }
    ... more properties
}

public class LevelDocumentList
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public string FolderAutomationId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    ... more properties
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

The default name for DocumentListRoot was Root and I changed that with no issues.  What I would like to do is to change the name of LevelDocumentList to a different name.  I have seen several posts here but they are pertaining to changing attribute names, not class names.  I did try parsing the JSON string and renaming the class there, and it works, but that seems like a hack.
I would like to know if there is a way while deserializing, to change the names of the classes.

You can change the name of the class to whatever you want. JSON deserialization only cares about the name of the properties.

Maybe you want to find this JsonPropertyName, Reference


Then you can change your class name as you need. Since deserialization
only cares about names of properties as @  gunr2171 said. You can
change your class name accordingly as well as work around but not a
hacky way of doing it.

Refer to the code below:
public class DocumentListRoot
{        
    public List<MyLevelDocumentList> LevelDocumentList { get; set; }  // New class name
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }
    // other remaining properties
}

public class MyLevelDocumentList // New class name
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public string FolderAutomationId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    public List<MyAttribute> Attributes { get; set; } // refer the new class name 
    // define other properties as usual 
}

public class MyAttribute // New class you want
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}


Thank you for the quick answer, however, this does not work.  Once the values are deserialized into the classes, LevelDocumentList is null, so my LINQ queries fail.  Also, I still ahve to refer to LevelDocumentList, not the new name.
So, basically I want to be able to change the class name and refer to it as the new name in any following C# code.

@JimboJones answer was updated to fit your case. refer to the above code and appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer if it solves the case and give an upvote too. Thanks in advance.

I used @gunr2171's suggestion
    public class DocumentListRoot
    {
        // This property name(LevelDocumentList) has to stay the same 
        //   for deserialization purposes.  Now I have a list of the 
        //   class with my new name.
        public List<MyNewName> LevelDocumentList { get; set; } 
        public string FileNumber { get; set; }
        ... more properties
    }

    public class MyNewName
    {
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string FolderAutomationId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
        public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
        ... more properties
    }

